# Using cp command in linux shell, how do I copy a whole directory into another directory?

Tags: linux, shell, cp

I have a directory, let's say, "work": ~/work/
This directory has some sub-folders (d1, d2...) in it and files in these sub-folders. I want to make a backup copy in the same folder, so it would be like: ~/backup/work/
However, when I use 
`cp -r ./work ./backup`
the folder "work" is not copied, only its subfoders (so now it's ~/backup/d1 ~/backup/d2...)
Any idea how to make it work? I'm quite new to shell, so I'm missing something :)

Comment: are you saying that the above case is what you *want* to happen, or what is *currently* happening? Can you rephrase / reformat your question to make this more clear?

Comment: I want to copy ./work to ./backup, so it will be ./backup/work. I could only come up with the command above, at it moves not "work", but its subfolders, so it looks like ./backup/d1 ("d1" is a subfolder in "work")

Comment: In that case, I think that @Petr Baudis's answer is the one you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cp will not create leading directories; when it sees a path that does not exist, it will assume that it shall be the new name of the directory being copied.

Try copying into a directory that already exists: `mkdir work` first, then `cp -r work backup`.

Comment: Thanks, I thought there was a way of copying the folder without creating a new folder with the same name, but now I see that is impossible with just cp command. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
rsync -avz ./work ./backup
```

Comment: Yeah I found info about `rsync`, but I had to figure out how to use it with `cp` :)

Answer (score 0):

```
cp -r ./work/ ./backup/
```

or

```
cp -r ./work ./backup/work
```

Comment: Tried this before, it gives out an error: "Cannot create directory './backup/src': No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

```
[max@localhost ~]$ mkdir aaa
[max@localhost ~]$ cd aaa
[max@localhost aaa]$ touch 1 2 3
[max@localhost aaa]$ mkdir bbb
[max@localhost aaa]$ touch 3 4 5
[max@localhost aaa]$ cd
```

This is The content of directory `aaa`

```
[max@localhost ~]$ ls -l aaa/
total 4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 max max    0 Oct 19 17:29 1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 max max    0 Oct 19 17:29 2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 max max    0 Oct 19 17:29 3
-rw-rw-r-- 1 max max    0 Oct 19 17:29 4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 max max    0 Oct 19 17:29 5
drwxrwxr-x 2 max max 4096 Oct 19 17:29 bbb
```

To copy any directory use **`cp -r` or `cp -R` or `cp --recursive`** command

Here `-r`, `-R`, `--recursive` **means copy directories recursively**

```
[max@localhost ~]$ cp -r aaa/ ccc/
[max@localhost ~]$ cd ccc/
[max@localhost ccc]$ ls -l
total 4
-rw-rw-r--  1 max max    0 Oct 19 17:30 1
-rw-rw-r--  1 max max    0 Oct 19 17:30 2
-rw-rw-r--  1 max max    0 Oct 19 17:30 3
-rw-rw-r--  1 max max    0 Oct 19 17:30 4
-rw-rw-r--  1 max max    0 Oct 19 17:30 5
drwxrwxr-x  2 max max 4096 Oct 19 17:30 bbb
```

Here content of directory `aaa` is copied to directory `ccc` including files and sub directory contents.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a Linux system:

```
cp -rT --parents work backup/work
```